# Documentation on Launching an application in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

This might be off the topic and I know stackoverflow is all about technical things, but, I think this will be important for most of the users.

Google play has a `detailed documentation` on how to upload one's apk files, get it billed, etc.,. But, going through all the documentation is a bit hard for the noobs. If someone can provide a document in Layman's perspective, just listing the steps on what and what to do, and if possible, how to do with an example, it would be great.

**for example :**

```
step 1 ::: Create a signed .apk file.
           Here is how you do it (with an example)

step 2 ::: Create a google play account
           Here is how you do it (with an example)

step 3 :::

step 4 :::

...
...

step n-4 ::: To make your app a paid application, here is what you have to do.

..


step n ::: Wait for few hours and you will have your application online.
```

If there is a link to such sources, please do share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:**

The documentation is pretty good regarding this:
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

**Step 2:**

Sign up and sign in here, $25.
https://play.google.com/apps/publish

In general, refer to this documentation:
http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/register.html

**More:**

Other steps, again the documentation is pretty good:
http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html

Comment: I agree, the documentation is thorough, with enough examples. I released my first application just by following these guides.